# killing the background process in a shell script

Tags: shell, process, busybox

I have a script that starts background processes.

```
#!/bin/sh

./process1.sh &
./process2.sh &
```

I need to kill these processes using a separate script.
Here is what I did:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the kill.sh

pid=$(ps | grep './process1.sh' |grep -v grep| awk '{print $1}')
kill -9 $pid
```

Question time:

1. When the kill.sh is called processes are stoped. But I get the message

   "sh: you need to specify whom to kill". 
   Why is that?
2. After I kill the process using the described script, it doesn't stop immediately.For a while I see the output on the screen as if the process is still running. Why?
3. What could be an alternative solution to kill the processes?

Worth to mention that I am working with busybox do I have limited choice of utilities.

Comment: Naturally, depends on how you have written these scripts, but you should allow for them to catch the signal (when performing a kill) and perform the required action to clean up - or shutdown gracefully.

Also, just record the PID when you start the process in the background as a temp file in the /tmp-directory, no need to mess around `ps` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the process ids in a temporary file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

./process1.sh &
echo $! > /tmp/process1.pid
./process2.sh &
echo $! > /tmp/process2.pid
```

and then delete it with your script. `$!` returns the PID of the process last executed.

```
kill -9 `cat /tmp/process*.pid`
rm /tmp/process*.pid
```

Make sure the `process*.pid` files get deleted after the corresponding script is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `kill` command failed as `pid` is empty.

```
pid=$(ps | grep './process1.sh' |grep -v grep| awk '{print $1}')
```

This doesn't give you the pid you want. When you start a process in the background, it's executed in a new shell and you won't see the `process.sh` in your `ps` output.

What you can do is save the PIDs when you start the background processes and kill them:

```
./process1.sh &
pid1=$!  # Save the previously started background's PID
./process2.sh &
pid2=$!  # Save the previously started background's PID

echo $pid1 " " $pid2 > /tmp/killfile
```

Then get the PIDs from this file and pass it to `kill`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I will try it.One question. It's wierd, you are telling me that my pid should be empty, but it's not. I have tested it, and it holds the PID of the process I am intending to kill and I do see the process in the ps list.

Comment: Running `ps` without any options as you do won't show all the processes. Can you just run ps on the console and see your process?

Comment: Yes I can see them using only ps. I assume it's cause of the busybox behaviour.